# How to remove files using find and rm command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
find -mmin -19 -exec rm '{}'\;
```

It will find the modified files 1st and then remove them.
but it gives me error as below,
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Also tried various combinations like,

```
find -mmin -19 -exec rm '{}';\
find -mmin -19 -exec rm '{}'/;
```

Comment: Use space to separate the `{}` and semicolon, and use `+` instead of semicolon, if you don't use the GNU-specific `-delete` option.

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need space between the command and `\;`

```
find -mmin -19 -exec rm {} \;
```

`find` already provide `-delete` option, so you don't need to use `-exec rm ..`:

```
find -mmin -19 -delete
```

---

> **-delete**
>
> Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed, an 
>   error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit status will
>   be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete automatically
>   turns on the -depth option.
>
> Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated as an
>   expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to delete
>   everything below the starting points you specified.  When testing a
>   find command line that you later intend  to  use  with
>   -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid later surprises.  Because -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot usefully
>   use -prune and -delete together.

Comment: Is it safe to use `find ./ -type f -iname \*.jpg -delete` to delete **only** `jpg` files?

Comment: It will delete all jpg file in current directory and sub-directories.

Comment: Take note that `-delete` option won't work on directories that aren't empty

Answer (score 5):

You're missing an essential space to separate the braces from the semicolon.

```
find -mmin -19 -exec rm '{}' \;
```

but this does the same ting, is easier to type, and probably executes faster.

```
find -mmin -19 -delete
```

Comment: It gives me error 

rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'
rm: cannot remove `./rm1': Is a directory


ls -a
.  ..  rm1

Comment: You cannot remove nonempty directories. If you want to remove the whole tree, make `find` run depth first.

Comment: add `-not -type d`  before the exec to avoid that error.

Comment: @tripleee you can't remove directories with a non-recursive `rm` at all

Comment: @Jasen But with `find -delete` you can.

Comment: ... But I see now that `-delete` already implies `-depth`. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. Specify the date from which we want to delete the files:

```
find /SYSADMIT/* -type f -not -newermt "AAAA:MM:DD HH:MI:SS" -delete
```

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/08/linux-borrar-ficheros-por-fecha.html